# How can I set the http proxy in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, http, proxy

I have code that needs to make an outbound http connection. However, I am behind a proxy.
I have seen examples of how to set the proxy parameters, but none of which allow me to specify my username and password.

Has anyone got an example to help me out?

Comment: Here is the contemporary solution (works from Eclipse 4.3 up) http://stackoverflow.com/a/34204939/715269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Apache HttpClient - http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientProxyAuthentication.java

Answer (score 5):

1. [Windows] -> [Preferences] -> [General] -> [Network Connections]
2. Set Active Provider to "Manual"
3. Select protocol (HTTP)
4. Click Edit
5. Click "Requires Authentication"
6. Provide creds

Comment: Spot on. Thank you very much indeed for the help!

Comment: May I just ask one more thing - Is there anything I need to do in my program after I specify the credentials? Thanks again.

Comment: You're program? Programs don't inherit Eclipse proxy settings; that's a separate question. You said "code" and I thought you where writing a plugin for eclipse.

Comment: Ah my bad. Essentially I am using JSOUP and am trying to retrieve the html from a url using the following: Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get(); It won't work because I am behind a proxy. I have seen how to specify the proxy name and port using the java system properties, but I can't find out how to specify a user name and password. Apologies for not being clear in the first instance.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a reference on configuration proxy information for any Java app. If you are running your app from Eclipse, you will want to set these in your launch configuration.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("30.40.50.60", 8080));
URL url = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com");
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. But does it allow me to include credentials as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this under Run->Run Configurations or Run->Debug Configurations, under the “Target” tab.  You’re looking for the “Additional Emulator Command Line Options” box.  In my case, the full string I used was -http-proxy http://username:password@10.0.0.1:3128 where username is my proxy login, password is my proxy password, 10.0.0.1 is my proxy IP address, 3128 is the port.

emulator settings from within the emulator.  I have no idea why this is necessary but it didn’t work without this change.  Once you launch the emulator, go to Settings->Wireless & Networks->Mobile Networks->Access Point Names->TelKila and set “Proxy” and “Port” to match the settings above