# proxy in eclipse 3.7

Tags: java, linux

Iam running eclipse 3.7  in ubuntu 11.10.my network connections run behind the proxy
I have set using the following link but it still not working.
[How can I set the http proxy in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291871/how-can-i-set-the-http-proxy-in-eclipse)
here is the error:

HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo/content.xml
Proxy auth required
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7/content.xml
Proxy auth required.

I can install updates.
Please,any help appreciated
huu

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing the proxies panel in eclipse?

Comment: That link discuss many different proxy settings :) in your case I would guess you want to set them in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows] -> [Preferences] -> [General] -> [Network Connections]
Set Active Provider to "Manual"
Select protocol (HTTP)
Click Edit
Click "Requires Authentication"
Provide creds