# eclipse couldn't connect internet?

Tags: eclipse, proxy, firewall, eclipse-marketplace

I can reach the `eclipse marketplace` using browser but i couldn't connect through `eclipse`.

It's not a `firewall` issue, i've already allow the `eclipse`.

What could be the reason, i use `eclipse luna`.

when i check the proxy `controlpanel > internet options > connections > lan settings`  the `automaticly detect settings` was checked. Could it be the proxy issue, if it is how can i get the proxy settings.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the contemporary solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/34204939/715269. (starting from 4.3 version). The other answer there works for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go to

```
Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections
```

1. Direct: No proxy will applicable and always look for direct connection
2. Manual: You can set your own proxy setting here also you can set username and password for internet login(if applicable)
3. Native: This will look for system proxy settings

[image]

Comment: where can i get my proxy host name and port ?

Comment: Added screen shot please refer it

Comment: Should i change the active provider to direct or what?

Comment: better keep it manual if you want to buy pass proxy or else not required

Comment: it is manual but it doesnt connect marketplace what could be the problem

Comment: do you have valid proxy settings? Are you able to connect internet without proxy settings?

Comment: There is proxy yeah but i dont know the proxy name and port where should i look.

Comment: you can find proxy settings under Internet Explorer -> Tools - Internet Options - > Connections - > LAN settings

Comment: it is empty actually automaticly detect settings is checked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68346/discussion-between-sasikumar-murugesan-and-cengiz-dogan).

Answer (score 0):

Just go to http://www.whatismyproxy.com/ and you will get your proxy server ip
You can use that IP in configuring the **NetworkConnections** setting in Eclipse
hope it helps